# Many-to-Many with "Primary"

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'm working on a database that needs to represent computers and their users. Each computer can have multiple users and each user can be associated with multiple computers, so it's a classic many-to-many relationship.  However, there also needs to be a concept of a "primary" user.  I have to be able to join against the primary user to list all computers with their primary users.  I'm not sure what the best way structure this in the database:

1) As I'm currently doing: linking table with a boolean IsPrimary column.  Joining requires something like ON (c.computer_id = l.computer_id AND l.is_primary = 1).  It works, but it feels wrong because it's not easy to constrain the data to only have one primary user per computer.

2) A field on the computer table that points directly at a user row, all rows in the user table represent non-primary users.  This represents the one-primary-per-computer constraint better, but makes getting a list of computer-users harder.

3) A field on the computer table linking to a row in the linking table.  Feels strange...

4) Something else?

What is the 'relational' way to describe this relationship?

EDIT: 
@Mark Brackett: The third option seems a lot less strange to me now that you've shown how nice it can look.  For some reason I didn't even think of using a compound foreign key, so I was thinking I'd have to add an identity column on the linking table to make it work. Looks great, thanks!

@j04t: Cool, I'm glad we agree on #3 now.

Comment: why it is hard to list the computer user on point 2?

Comment: Because the linking table doesn't contain all the users for a given computer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Option 3, though it may feel strange, is the closest to what you want to model. You'd do something like:

```
User { 
   UserId 
   PRIMARY KEY (UserId) 
}

Computer { 
   ComputerId, PrimaryUserId
   PRIMARY KEY (UserId) 
   FOREIGN KEY (ComputerId, PrimaryUserId) 
      REFERENCES Computer_User (ComputerId, UserId) 
}

Computer_User { 
   ComputerId, UserId 
   PRIMARY KEY (ComputerId, UserId)
   FOREIGN KEY (ComputerId) 
      REFERENCES Computer (ComputerId)
   FOREIGN KEY (UserId) 
      REFERENCES User (UserId)
}
```

Which gives you 0 or 1 primary user (the PrimaryUserId can be nullable if you want), that must be in Computer_User. Edit: If a user can only be primary for 1 computer, then a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on Computer.PrimaryUserId will enforce that. Note that there is no requirement that all users be a primary on some computer (that would be a 1:1 relationship, and would call for them to be in the same table).

Edit: Some queries to show you the simplicity of this design

```
--All users of a computer
SELECT User.* 
FROM User 
JOIN Computer_User ON 
   User.UserId = Computer_User.UserId 
WHERE 
   Computer_User.ComputerId = @computerId

--Primary user of a computer
SELECT User.* 
FROM User 
JOIN Computer ON 
   User.UserId = Computer.PrimaryUserId
WHERE 
   Computer.ComputerId = @computerId

--All computers a user has access to
SELECT Computer.*
FROM Computer
JOIN Computer_User ON
   Computer.ComputerId = Computer_User.ComputerId
WHERE
   Computer_User.UserId = @userId

--Primary computer for a user
SELECT Computer.*
FROM Computer
WHERE
    PrimaryUserId = @userId
```

Comment: The FK Computer -> CompUser enforces that the primary user for a computer is indeed one of that computer's users. Strictness is good :)

Comment: Thanks for the post. It got me looking at the relationship in a way that initially seems foreign, but really works well.

Comment: I liked it! On a theorical point of view, we are saying here that we have a "one-to-many" relationship called "is the primary user of computer ..." in addition to the "many-to-many" relationship called "is a user of computer". Did someone see any limitation to this proposal?

Comment: The problem that I see with this is there is a chance for data inconsistency.  There is a possibility that the user ID indicated in the PrimaryUserID field might not be in the Computer_User link table for that Computer record.  What then?  Who is correct?

Comment: I agree with Mark.  The primary user may indeed not be a user, so if you want all users, you would have to include both the primary user, and the other computer users, and remember to do distinct, so the primary user wouldn't appear twice if he was both a user, and a primary user.

Comment: @Mark & Kibbee: Look again. The Computer table has a foreign key from (ComputerId, PrimaryUserId) to the Computer_User table. There is no possibility for inconsistency there.

Answer (score 1):

Edit -- 
I didn't think properly about it the first 3 times through...
I vote for --
(Number 3 solution)

Users

```
user id (pk)
```

Computers

```
computer id (pk)
primary user id (fk -> computer users id)
```

Computer Users

```
user id (pk) (fk -> user id)
computer id (pk) (fk -> user id)
```

This is the best solution I can think of.

Why I like this design.

1) Since this is a relationship involving computers and users I like the idea of being able to associate a user to multiple computers as the primary user.  This may not ever occur where this database is being used though.

2) The reason I don't like having the primary_user on the link table

```
 (computer_users.primary_user_id fk-> users.user_id)
```

is to prevent a computer from ever having multiple primary users.

Given those reasons Number 3 solution looks better since you will never run into some possible problems I see with the other approaches.

Solution 1 problem - Possible to have multiple primary users per computer.

Solution 2 problem - Computer links to a primary user when the computer and user aren't link to each other.

```
computer.primaryUser = user.user_id
computer_users.user_id != user.user_id
```

Solution 3 problem - It does seem kind of odd doesn't it?  Other than that I can't think of anything.

Solution 4 problem - I can't think of any other way of doing it.

---

This is the 4th edit so I hope it makes sense still.

Comment: This still doesn't solve the problem of determining a "primary" user.

Answer (score 0):

Since the primary user is a function of the computer and the user I would tend to go with your approach of having the primaryUser being a column on the linking table.

The other alternative that I can think of is to have a primaryUser column directly on the computer table itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would have made another table PRIMARY_USERS with unique on `computer_id` and making both `computer_id` and `user_id` foreign keys of USERS.

Answer (score 0):

Either solution 1 or 2 will work. At this point I would ask myself which one will be easier to work with. I've used both methods in different situations though I would generally go with a flag on the linking table and then force a unique constraint on computer_id and isPrimaryUser, that way you ensure that each computer will only have one primary user.

Comment: except for the obvious flaw of non primary users having duplicated computer_id, isPrimaryUser values....

Comment: Simply implement a second unique key so that user_id and isPrimaryUser must also be unique. Keeps everything at home in one table.

Comment: IsPrimaryUser can be either 0 or 1. Therefore, your (UserId, IsPrimary) unique key would have a user be *at most* 1 non primary user (UserId, IsPrimary = 0) and 1 primary user (UserId, IsPrimary = 1). Your (ComputerId, IsPrimary) has a similar flaw.

Comment: After posting, I realized the flaw in the (UserId, IsPrimary) key. Thanks for your post though which shows a better way.

Answer (score 0):

2 feels right to me, but I would test out 1, 2 and 3 for performance on the sorts of queries you normally perform and the sorts of data volumes you have.

As a general rule of thumb I tend to believe that where there is a choice of implementations you should look to your query requirements and design your schema so you get the best performance and resource utilisation in the most common case.

In the rare situation where you have equally common cases which suggest opposite implementations, then use Occam's razor.

Comment: I'd disagree that you have much choice when it comes to relational modeling. There *is* a right way, and a wrong way. The wrong way may perform better - but it'll be a maintenance issue. Sometimes, we have to make that trade off, but it should be a conscious choice.

Comment: Just to follow up - option 2 is *wrong* because it would allow a user to be both a primary user (by being in Computer.PrimaryUserId) and a non primary user (by being in Computer_User) for the same computer at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar situation in the application I work on where we have Accounts that can have many Customers attached but only one should be the Primary customer.

We use a link table (as you have) but have a Sequence value on the link table.  The Primary user is the one with Sequence = 1.  Then, **we have an Index on that Link table for AccountID and Sequence to ensure that the combination of AccountID** and Sequence is unique (thereby ensuring that no two Customers can be the Primary one on an Account).  So you would have:

```
LEFT JOIN c.computer_id = l.computer_id AND l.sequence = 1
```